# How to build a associative-array type O(1) field n mongodb schema

Tags: arrays, mongodb, associative-array

I have started on Mongo only recently, and am adapting myself to thinking *document* instead of a *table* based approach.

I have a Schema that looks like (Node.js):

```
var UserInfo = new mongoose.Schema({
    id: Number,
    name: String,
    friends: [{
        id: Number,
        name: String,
    }]
    }, {
        collection: 'userInfo'
    });
```

The issue is that if I know my User's id and his friend's id too, I will have to iterate through the entire friends[] to find the friend. In other words, the entire operation is not O(1).

If I were storing this in a JS data structure, I will use an associative array for friends, some something like `myuser.friends[his_friend_id]` will give me a O(1) access to the friend. How do I achieve the same O(1) in Mongo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was looking for was a [sub-document](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html)

> Finding a sub-document
>
> Each document has an _id. DocumentArrays have a special id method for
>   looking up a document by its _id.

```
var doc = parent.children.id(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with mongoose, but if there are issues with creating the structure as you think it should be, then there is good reason for that. My current thinking is that the keys in a nosql schema should never be dynamic as it makes searching difficult, if not impossible.

eg with your current schema you would be able to a search for a user in the friends attribute with something like

```
userInfo.find({ 'friends.id' = userId })
```

You can also do

```
userInfo.find({ id: userId, 'friends.id' = friendId })
```

but I'm not sure that you could return only the individual friend's data from the search anyway.

If you never need to do similar, then it would appear that you must be storing the relationship in both user's documents, duplicating the data. In that case you might want to consider a collection which simply maps friends to friends, or only store the relationships initiated by a user in that user's friends list.

To answer the actual question, I don't think you want to change your schema, but rather go with loading the user and just doing a filter/first/someother type array search on the list of friends to find the match.

Comment: Thanks for userInfo.find({ id: userId, 'friends.id' = friendId }) . You are right, though, that this query will return the document that contains the friends[] array nit the individual element in the friends[] array itself. Also, I suspect that find() will eventually do a linear search through the friends[] array. My question can be rephrased as "whether its possible to create an index for a <list> type field in mongodb" . Clearly, we can index a certain schema by creating a Hashed Index ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-hashed/ ) for a certain field, but the filed should be a scalar

Comment: I just think this is likely premature optimisation. I know the thought of looping through all the friends just feels wasteful but unless the user has 100,000 friends it's really not going to be noticeable, and even then it's unlikely to be your slowest moving part. In the instance of "storing this in a JS data structure" you have already loaded the object so then it's just a search through an array. If you want to be doing 1,000's of these lookups at a time then you don't want to be loading the full user objects either.

Answer (score 0):

The entire operation of retrieving the user document and getting the friend will never be O(1), because lookups in MongoDB aren't O(1). But you can avoid searching the `friends` array for the friend. Use `$` projection:

```
> db.test.drop()
> db.test.insert({ "_id" : 0, "friends" : [{ "_id" : 1 }, { "_id" : 2 }, { "_id" : 3 }] })
> db.test.find({ "_id" : 0, "friends._id" : 2 }, { "friends.$" : 1 })
{ "_id" : 0, "friends" : [ { "_id" : 2 } ] }
```

Comment: Thanks for $ projection. It is just a filtering tool in my understanding (much like LIKE in SQL). I was hoping that the mongo guys have thought of a way of indexing within indexing. Also, I would imagine that lookups by index or primary key ( for mongo, it is perhaps _id) must be O(1). Anyways, I will leave the question unanswered for a little while. Thanks for you time.